# React Select Async options not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have an API call which is returning data and the best I can see I am returning the options in the correct way but for some reason I can't get React Select to show the options. Is there something that I am missing?

```
searchGroups(searchString){
    if(!searchString) return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
    UserGroups.getUserGroups(searchString).then((res) => {
      let groups = [];
      groups = res.groups.map((d) => ({
        value: d.group_ID,
        label: d.group_name
      }))
      return {options: groups};
    }, (e) => {
      this.setState({
        searchError: e.message
      })
    })
  }
```

From what I can see the `groups` array is (upon a search) returning as

```
[
    {value: 1, label: "Admins"}
    {value: 22, label: "Asset Group"}
    {value: 2, label: "Read-only"}
]
```

However the search box is being suspended with a "loading..." message and the load spinner stays. I can see the API has returned but no options are being displayed.

This is how I implement the `Select` is there an option I am missing? I have tried both `valueKey` and `labelKey` but neither have worked for me either.

```
<Select.Async
      multi={true}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      loadOptions={this.searchGroups}
      value={this.state.value}
 />
```

I'm sure it is how I'm returning the data but not sure where this is going wrong and what formatting I need to correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `return UserGroups.getUserGroups(..`.

Comment: @Oblosys, I've just lost 2 hours to that. Should have just stepped back and taken another look. Many thanks for pointing that obvious flaw out. Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a missing `return` before `UserGroups.getUserGroups(..`. This caused the async code to get executed and show up in the network log, but the results wouldn't reach `Select.Async`. It would be nice if `react-select` would give an error if calling `loadOptions` returns `undefined`, but in that case it assumes a callback will be used to provide the result.